# How to populate a new windows form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I am trying to write a function that opens a new browser window and populate the email and login field and then click the submit button all from Javascript.

Lets say my domain is **mynewweb.com** and I want to open **facebook.com/login** page and populate the *email* and *password*  fields from javascript code (such as document.getElementById) and then submit the form using some javascript code as well.

Is there any way of achieving that, any ideas. At the moment I am unable to achieve that I think its CORS issue but i'm not sure. But any idea of achieving that functionality or out of the box approach or something would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, then you want a function that's *not* based on websites, but on browser functionality.
There are plenty of form filling plugins for different browsera, just look on their addons page.